# Empty graph when loaded in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use plotly with angular 2 and it is showing me an empty bar graph initially and it only shows me the graph when i double click on the graph area.

Comment: are you populating the plotty graph variable in the constructor or ngOnInit i:e when the class loads

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No DOM element with id 'myDiv' exists on the page.                                                                                                               But my div id='myDiv' is present inside the html page

Comment: can you post your code , always its a good practice to have heavy methods in ngOnInit Instead of constructor

Comment: ngOnInit() 
   {var data = [{
            
            values: barChartData,
            labels: barChartLabels,
            type: 'pie'
        }];  Plotly.newPlot('pieDiv', data, layout); }

Comment: <div id="pieDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 380px;" ></div>

Comment: what is the error in my code

Comment: please add it to the question for better readbality